# "Putting the number billion in a tangible way blows your mind" is this sentence correct?

Tags: sentence-meaning, word-in-context

So I want to convey the message that the number billion when expressed in a realistic example that even a layman can relate to using the word tangible. And how can I say the same thing using the word palpable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A “billion” doesn’t seem like much at first, but when you have a tangible example (or make it tangible), the scale blows your mind.

Comment: Thanks. That's a nice way to put it. Can I replace tangible with palpable without having to change anything in the sentence?

Comment: @WinterSoldier I’ve only seen palpable used with feelings like fear or tension; I don’t know what else it is (or isn’t) appropriate for. I know for sure tangible works here, so that’s what I’d use.

Comment: Does it make any sense to say that a billion doesn't "seem like much at first"?

Comment: I am reminded of the father of the famous (to older people) Gilbreth family, who showed his kids what a million looked like by sticking sheets of graph paper together on a wall that had 1/24th inch squares (it was the USA in the 1950s) to make a square 1000 x 1000.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey “A billion here, a billion there, and pretty soon you’re talking real money.” It all depends on perspective.

Comment: How many people think one billion is not very much? Seriously.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey A billion grains of sand won’t even make one castle.

Comment: But it would be tedious to count them,

Answer (score 0):

"Blows your mind" is a somewhat informal, even slangy expression, but the sentence is grammatical. Palpable is a direct synonym of tangible.

Comment: What can be the elegant way to construct the sentence? It seems off to me